# Download of "Samples" of downloadable products restricted by group

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable

i'm building an e-commerce web site with different types of products.

I have many downloadable products like **documents, images, videos** but all of them are available for download for free.

I do not want the users have to go to the checkout process to download so i'm thinking to use the **"Samples"** section to let them download what they want.

But now i want that only some Particular group can download this material.

Now i would like to ask you: Is it possible to restrict the "Samples" download only for particular group?

Thank you very much and any suggestion is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At the moment i found this solution that work for me.
I know is not the best solution because i'm gonna to modify 1 core file.

I have modified the "**public static function getBasePath()**" that is responsable to retrieve sample files path inside the "**Sample.php**" inside this folder "**app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/**"

I have added an IF condition to check the groupID:

```
public static function getBasePath()
    {
            $_groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();          

            if ($_groupId === '4') {
                return Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'downloadable' . DS . 'files' . DS . 'samples';
            }
    }
```

Any suggestion is really appreciated